# How to Display product offer for a limited period in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7, php-carbon

I need to display as as the product Status is special for a selected date from X date to X date,

This is how my UI Looks like
[image]

This is the place where a user can create a new sub category and select a special offer dates

[image]

This is my Show Function in my Controller

```
 public function show(Category $category)
{
    // ! Search Filter
    $filter = new SearchFilter();
    $filter->where('parent_id','=',$category->id);

    // ! Date Filter (Today)
     $day = Carbon::now();
     $today = $day->toDateString();
   

    return view('manage.categories.show')->with([
        'pageTitle' => $category->name,
        'allItems' => $this->dataRepo->search([], $filter),
        'isDestroyingEntityAllowed' => $this->isDestroyingEntityAllowed,
        'entity' => $category,
        'today'=>$today,
    ]);
}
```

This is my blade where it checks the date

```
@foreach ($allItems as $item)
            <td>
                @if ($item->special_start == $today || $item->special_end == $today)
                    Special
                    @else
                    Regular
                @endif
            </td>

    @endforeach
```

But this will show **Special** only if it matches the date with start date and end date,  the days between the start date and the end date will be shown as **Regular**.

How can i fix it ?

Comment: i have posted answer please take a look

Comment: @KamleshPaul i get this error Object of class Illuminate\Support\Carbon could not be converted to int

Comment: i updated the code now check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Carbon` it is not recommended to write logic in `view` but you can move this to controller

```php
@foreach ($allItems as $item)
<td>
    @php
        $first = \Carbon\Carbon::create($item->special_start);
        $second = \Carbon\Carbon::create($item->special_end);
        $diff = now()->between($first, $second);
    @endphp
    @if ($diff)
    Special
    @else
    Regular
    @endif
</td>
@endforeach
```

ref link https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison